# puppet client side set variable if file exists on client machine

Tags: puppet

novice question here. I know it is similar to others here but i am not finding i can apply those answers in my case

i have 2 servers that are blades and 2 that are regular rack mount servers. a puppet script runs on all 4. i want to set a specific value in $sriov_device if the script is running on a blade, but not the other servers.

the blades both have a /usr/local/blade file existing

in a manifest script am trying something like this, but $sriov_device is not being set

```
file { "/usr/local/blade":
  ensure => present,
  replace => false,
}

whatever {"foo":
  $sriov_device = "eno2"
  require => File["/usr/local/blade"],
}
```

thanks, sincerely,

-- novice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect NVIDIA GPU with Puppet](https://serverfault.com/questions/952825/how-to-detect-nvidia-gpu-with-puppet). You need to define a custom fact that will distinguish between the blades and other servers.

Comment: Actually, there are likely already existing facts that you can use. See the various DMI  facts under `$facts['dmi']`. There are ones for the hardware manufacturer and product name which should be set to something sensible, certainly they work for the major server vendors like Dell and HP, etc.

Comment: ah nice thanks you very much. this worked for me


`if ($type == 'Blade') {

 $sriov_device = "eno2"

} else {

 $sriov_device = "None"

  }`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
if ($type == 'Blade') { 
 $sriov_device = "eno2" 
} else {
 $sriov_device = "None" 
}
```

I was trying to use `if ($facts[Type] == "Blade"`, but I kept getting the error that "Facts was not a hash or array", so then I tried the above which uses the classic facts which just uses the fact name `$type`.